# Как написать мок используя NSubstitute. что бы в тесте получать отправляемые в лог сообщения

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

Есть  тестируемый метод  который на входе получает logger 
хочу написать мок таким образом что бы получить в тесте анализировать отправленные в лог сообщения.

```
var logger= Substitute.For<ILogger>();

logger.AddMessage(ProtocolMessageTypes.Debug,"бла бала");
logger.AddMessage(ProtocolMessageTypes.Error,"Error");
```

хотелось бы получить что то типа

```
List<ILogMessages> messages=  Logger.GetMessages()
```

Comment: Почему бы не написать просто заглушку для логгера? Или обязательно  хотите каждый раз настраивать прокси от Substitute для этого?

Comment: Да и требование странное, для чего могло бы понадобиться проверять логгирование?

Comment: Я исследую возможности  NSubstitute и вроде как бы что то похожее он может (например посчитать количество вызовов). Далее на самом деле задача другая  просто я придумал пример с логгером. что бы не объяснять тонкости.

Comment: Ну и если это граница возможностей Nsubstitute готов использовать Rhino Mock  или любой другой. Если не получится, то  со спокойным сердцем буду использовать самопальный мок объект.

Comment: Стоит задача протоколировать действия.Проверяю  что объект пишет в лог соответствующие сообщения.Что здесь странного?

Comment: У меня не так много опыта с nsubstitute, но есть подозрение, что под ваши нужды можно приспособить вот это http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-for-args/

Comment: Странно то, что в юнит тестах обычно проверяют логику программы, то есть тот код, что доставляет пользу конечному юзеру. А вы проверяете логгирование, что само по себе не для юзера, а для саппорта/девелопера, вот я и удивился такой задаче

Comment: по поводу протоколирования действий юзера - это по сути не логирование, а аудит. Чуть чуть другое понятие. Аудит, например, может быть использован в рамках самой системы, если есть юзеры, которые следят за другими юзерами.

Answer (score 0):

Это действительно очень просто **если знать как**.
NSubsittute на высоте. Хотя именно такого примера в helpe по моему нехватает.
Вот слегка модифицированный пример из NSubsittute help. Нужно было использовать индексер к коллекции входных параметров.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void SayHello(string to);
}
[Test]
public void SayHello()
{
    var cals = new List<string>();
    var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
    foo.When(x => x.SayHello(Arg.Any<string>()))
        .Do(x =>
        {
            cals.Add(x[0].ToString());//вот здесь весь смысл
        });
    foo.SayHello("World");
    Assert.AreEqual(cals[0], "World");
}
```

Я не стал заморачиваться делая пример с логгером принцип понятен а далее можно все что хочешь наклепать.